# Web service call fails but returns no error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to call a web service from a user control.

Here is the code of the web service:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WizardService:System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetNumber()
        {
            return "000000000000";
        }
    }
```

And here is the javascript:

```
 $('#' + '<%= btnMoveNext.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/Project/Services/WizardService.asmx";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "{}",
            url: requestUri + "/GetNumber",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnFail
        });
    })
```

When this code executes it always goes in the function OnFail. No error is displayed.

If this helps:

If I try to be more specific when calling the service(if I add - `async: false` or `dataType: "json"`) I get an internal server error. Otherwise there is no error but I tried to debug it and it did not enter the web service.

```
function OnFail() {
        alert("Failed");
    }
```

when I look at the requests in Fiddler I get a 401 Unauthorized with message:

{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Comment: can you give the code for the OnFail function?

Comment: For now it does nothing but I have put it in the question

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using 2010 or 2013? 2010 doesn't have the `webAbsoluteUrl` property available. Try removing `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` and just using the relative layouts url.

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

401 error means the URL resource requires user authentication.  And one of two conditions exist.

1. User authentication which has not been provided.
2. User authentication has failed.

If you do not know why your HTTP resource is requiring authentication, the best bet is to contact the administrator and open a dialogue with them.